# In Ipython Qt Console sp.info doesn't print inside the console

Tags: qt, numpy, scipy, ipython, qtconsole

I have installed IPython 1.1.0, in Ubuntu 12.04 from the source.

Similarly I have installed Numpy-1.8.0, Scipy-0.13.1, Matplotlib-1.3.1 from the source.

When I use the Ipython Qt COnsole the command sp.info(optimize.fmin) doesn't print the output in console but it prints it in the terminal (pylab). Is there anyway that it can print it in console too.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import optimize
sp.info(optimize.fmin)
```

The output is like this in pylab

```
fmin(func, x0, args=(), xtol=0.0001, ftol=0.0001, maxiter=None, maxfun=None,
full_output=0, disp=1, retall=0, callback=None)
Minimize a function using the downhill simplex algorithm.
Parameters
----------
func : callable func(x,*args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IPython's `?` syntax to get information about any object:

```
optimize.fmin?
```

That will work in all IPython environments.

However, `scipy.info()` and `numpy.info()` both work in the Qt console when I try them, whether or not I start it in pylab mode. I'm not sure why they don't for you.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for the reply. `optimize.fmin?` did work for ipython it showed the info but didn't embed it inside the qtconsole like it does it in terminal. Actually the scipy.info() and numpy.info() used to work with me too when I had installed each and everythin from the repository but the versions being bit old so I downloaded the latest versions from their websites and installed it from the source. After that it is not working.